# Visual Code Run Build Task npm

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code **1.13.0** on Windows 10.
I have the following *build script* in my `package.json`:

```
{
  //omitted other props
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack"
  }
}
```

I've installed [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) with `npm install --global webpack`, so it's installed globally.

The `webpack.config.js` is irrelevant for my question.

When I run `npm run build` in the terminal, everything works fine. But when I run the Visual Code *Tasks: Run Build Task* (`ctrl+shift+b` or `ctrl+shift+p > Run Build Task`), then I'm getting the following message in the output window:

> '"npm run build"' is not recognized as an internal or external
>   command, operable program or batch file.

Why? (*using npm version: 3.10.10*)

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: Also, what are the contents of ` tasks.json`?

Comment: I didn't have `tasks.json`, somehow I thought this was not needed and built in into Visual Code and that the command would recognize the `package.json`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should create tasks.json file and specify build task with npm task runner as described [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks) ctrl+shift+p > Configure Task Runner. In your case task.json file should looks something like that

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "npm",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "showOutput": "always",
    "suppressTaskName": true,
    "tasks": [
        {
            "isBuildCommand": true,
            "taskName": "build",
            "args": ["run", "build"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: The isShellCommand is now outdated. The `"type": "npm"` is the new format.

Answer (score 3):

`tasks.json` can be used for running multiple different tasks. This is @oleg-m's answer updated for version 2 of `tasks.json`:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "type":"npm",
            "script": "build",
            "group": "build"
        }
    ]
}
```